# change custom design of all product via single query or override rule

Tags: magento-1.8, product, custom

I noticed some former developer added custom design to all products. So now there are 1 000+ products and it is impossible to manually edit all of them and change the custom theme value to `null` so that all products will use the default theme.

How can I do this via Phpmyadim or any easy way like module override?

Answer (score 1):

First backup your database in case I'm wrong. Then....

Identify the attribute id.

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id, attribute_code
FROM 
    eav_attribute
WHERE
    attribute_code = 'custom_design' AND
    entity_type_id  = (SELECT 
                           entity_type_id
                       FROM
                           eav_entity_type
                       WHERE
                           entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
                       )
```

Then delete all the records from the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` with the `attribute_id` the one you get from the query above.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where `attribute_id` = 'attribute id from previous query';
```

Clear the cache and reindex.

Comment: i used your 1st query it did not give any result

Comment: I had a mistake in the query. Sorry. You can try again